# Does SonarLint support the CLR C++ project analyze?

Tags: sonarlint

I use Visual Studio 2022 and SonarLint 7.2.0 for work. And I have a project in the solution that should use a managed C++. So I created a project with a "CLR Console App (.NET Framework)" template. When I write some code I see in the bottom bar message "SonarLint failed to analyze the ConsoleApplication1.cpp file".

I tested SonarLint with the C# project or with the Native C++ project - all works fine. So does it mean that SonarLint doesn't support the CLR C++ project? Or should I add some options/settings, or buy some additional licenses?